# axios request locally works, but fails on lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, axios, get

I have the following js function:

```
const axios = require('axios');

exports.handler = async () => {
    console.log('checking your node...', process.env.PUBLIC_KEY);
    axios.get(process.env.REQUEST_URL + process.env.PUBLIC_KEY,{}).then((res) => {
        const response = res.data.data[0];
        if (response.status == "active_offline"){
            
            axios.post(process.env.SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL, {text: " Your node is offline!"});
            return console.log('Your node is offline!');
        }
        else {
            return console.log(" Your node is online.");
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
    });
    
}
```

Locally, this function works as expected. When run from my AWS lambda function, I do not see anything past `axios.get(process.env.REQUEST_URL +...`. I also do not get an error.

How can I further debug and figure out why this works locally, but not on Lambda?

Comment: Simplest fix is probably to use await with axios.get and then again with axios.post. Right now your Lambda function returns nothing at all because the return statements all execute inside a callback handler.

Comment: I understand that's definitely an issue for the `axios.post`, but the `axios.get` is indeed awaited via `.then()` (and this is why it works locally for me). Would `await` (vs `.then()`) make a significant difference here?

Comment: The axios.get is not awaited because your Lambda function handler doesn't return a promise. The underlying Lambda execution environment will simply end your Lambda function invocation when the function handler returns. It won't wait for the async callback to your axios.get call. A native Node.js app would not immediately exit because there is work scheduled (your axios.get call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Axios is a promise based HTTP client library.

The `axios.post()` is a non-blocking call which returns a **promise** instead of blocking there. So your program is exiting soon after making this call. That's the reason you're not seeing anything past that call.

So if you want your program to wait for the result then call like this,

```
await axios.post(process.env.SLACK_WEBHOOK_URL, {text: " Your node is offline!"});
```

Comment: Ah, yes this is indeed a mistake but I'm not sure it's what's causing the issue I'm seeing. I don't really care to await the line you mentioned, which is why this functions as expected locally.  On Lambda, i'm not seeing any execution past `axios.get`. I put logs in the following lines and none are hit immediately after `axios.get`, and that promise is awaited via `.then()`

Comment: @jamesdlivesinatree  when you are using .then() your execution is not blocking there, you are expecting a result after that axios call at some point in future and you will get that result in this then() callback.But this doesn't mean that your lambda main thread wait for your then() execution or your then() is awaiting (blocking). Your lambda method will terminates as soon as it executes axios call since it's an asynchronous non blocking call.

Comment: understood, and i appreciate your explanation! I'm still very curious why `await` will make a difference, though. `async/await` is syntactic sugar for promise chaining (src: https://medium.com/geekculture/does-async-await-block-javascript-main-thread-c07db9c48c3e).   I'm going to try your solution, but i'm still not understanding why it'd be any different than the code in my question (from axios.get..understood about axios.post).

Comment: okay, using `await` did work. but can you help me understand why? if `async/await` are just syntactic sugar for `.then()`, why the difference in output?  would it have made a difference if i declared my handler as `exports.handler = () => { ...` instead of `exports.handler = async () => { ...` ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60006844/lambda-execution-quits-before-asynchronous-event-is-finished